# How to sort elements by label value (using native JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can't solve it... How to sort elements by label value (using native JavaScript)? The main problem is that some of the checkboxes should be checked. Here is the piece of my HTML:

```
  <div class="checkboxesArea">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1" id="checkboxG1" class="css-checkbox" checked/>
        <label for="checkboxG1" class="css-label radGroup1">OOCSS</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG2" id="checkboxG2" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="checkboxG2" class="css-label radGroup1">Pug(Jade)</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG3" id="checkboxG3" class="css-checkbox" />
        <label for="checkboxG3" class="css-label radGroup1">Stylus/LESS/SASS</label>

    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why is the fact that some checkboxes should be checked a problem? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RichGoldMD i was thinking about apllying to labels method array.sort(). Or this method http://jsfiddle.net/2YRWs/1/  But the fact that some of the checkboxes should be checked makes the task more comlicated. So i guess i can't use none of it methods, or at least i don't know how. I stuck with checked checkbox... And how to sort the labels in order A-z

Comment: Deal with the DOM. `append(list)` and don't create new nodes by changing the `html()` of an element. But you were talking about "native JavaScript" and show a fiddle of something different with jquery. So what is it? And you still didn't show what your code looks like.

Comment: Hint: if you use this structure `<label><input></label>` you can get rid of the `for` attribute on the label and the `id` on the input. And you can sort a simple list of nodes and don't have to deal with how to keep `input` and `label` together.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for some of your help, i've solve it

Answer (score 1):

I've solve it. Here is the code

```js
    function myFunction() {

    var sort_by_name = function(a, b) {
        a = a.textContent.toLowerCase();
        b = b.textContent.toLowerCase();
        if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            // a must be equal to b
            return 0;
        }
    }


    var bigList = document.getElementById('checkboxesArea');


    var list = [];
    list = document.getElementsByClassName("singleCheckbox");
    var arr = [].slice.call(list);
    console.log(arr);
    function sortTheHellOutOfIt () {
        arr.sort(sort_by_name);
    };
    sortTheHellOutOfIt ();
    console.log(arr);
    bigList.innerHTML = "";
    console.log(arr[1]);
    function loop () {
        for (i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
            bigList.append(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    loop();
    /* bigList.html(arr); */


}
myFunction();
```

```css
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
    position:absolute; z-index:-1000; left:-1000px; overflow: hidden; clip: rect(0 0 0 0); height:1px; width:1px; margin:-1px; padding:0; border:0;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label, input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label.clr {
    padding-left: 25px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_5b5bfbefda397e42988ac41ac712d977.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-weight: bold;

}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label, input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label.chk {
    background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_5b5bfbefda397e42988ac41ac712d977.png);
    background-position: 0 -30px;
}
label.css-label {
    background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_5b5bfbefda397e42988ac41ac712d977.png);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
        <div id="checkboxesArea" class="checkboxesArea">

            <div class="singleCheckbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1" id="checkboxG1" class="css-checkbox" />
                <label for="checkboxG1" class="css-label radGroup1">БЭМ/OOCSS</label>
            </div>
            <div class="singleCheckbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG2" id="checkboxG2" class="css-checkbox" />
                <label for="checkboxG2" class="css-label radGroup1">Pug(Jade)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="singleCheckbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG3" id="checkboxG3" class="css-checkbox" />
                <label for="checkboxG3" class="css-label radGroup1">Stylus/LESS/SASS</label>
            </div>
     </div>
```